# How to I create a loop that uses the last column in an array as the starting point for the next loop? In matlab

Tags: matlab-guide

I have `output = A(:,Nout)`       `Nout = points along the array..... : =` all points in column

So, it is saying the values in the last column.

How do I use output as A at the first column for the next iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. You may mean a variety of things.

If you want to loop through values in the first column in some order specified by your last column you can:

```
Asort = A ( A (:, end), :);
```

and then loop through Asort.

You may also mean to loop N times for each row where N is defined by last column of A.
You can do it using a nested loop:

```
for Arow = A(:, end)  
    for ii = 1:Arow

        % your code here

    end
end
```

You may also mean several other things, but instead me guessing you could try clarifing a bit. :)
(it should be a comment but I can't add comments yet, sorry)